# Expect a variable to be null or boolean

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am developing some tests with Jest for a Node.js backend and I need to check out some values that come from a third party. In some cases those values can come as a `boolean` or as `null`.

Right now I am checking the variables that fit that situation with:

```
expect(`${variable}`).toMatch(/[null|true|false]/);
```

Is there any better way to check them with Jest built in functions?

Comment: Your current solution will also match strings "null", "true" and "false", which might not be preferred.

Comment: @FINDarkside that's why I am looking for a better solution with Jest methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about

```
expect(variable === null || typeof variable === 'boolean').toBeTruthy();
```

You can use [expect.extend](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectextendmatchers) to add it to the in-build matchers:

```
expect.extend({
    toBeBooleanOrNull(received) {
        return received === null || typeof received === 'boolean' ? {
            message: () => `expected ${received} to be boolean or null`,
            pass: true
        } : {
            message: () => `expected ${received} to be boolean or null`,
            pass: false
        };
    }
});
```

And use it like:

```
expect(variable).toBeBooleanOrNull();
```

Comment: Could also use this code with [expect.extend](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3457) to make this a built in `toBeBooleanOrNull`

Comment: I like the combined answer of you both. I leave up to you to update it or let @CodingIntrigue to answer it with the extend approach.

Comment: Could you do some like expect.any() but that includes null?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of expressing the condition using matchers *(can be combined with the approach to extend, as suggested in the answer by @bugs)*:

```
expect([expect.any(Boolean), null]).toContainEqual(variable);
```